# Arithmetic overflow error // converting numeric to data type numeric. // decimal (18,2)

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have a field in database as Decimal(18,2)
and i am trying to insert "2548745213698563.00" in it.

its throwing me error
"Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric."

What can be the issue?

Comment: Make it `(20,2)`. The 18 is the total length, not just what is in front of the dot.

Comment: create table t(n Decimal(18,2));
insert t values(2548745213698563.00);
select * from t;  Runs ok on Sql Server for example

Comment: the field is for price and when i am converting value in c# by convert.todecimal() its showing 2548745213698563.00M... is it correct ?